# Showing that a non-hyperbolic linear map is not structurally stable

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

Let $A \in GL(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $A$ is not hyperbolic (i.e $A$ has at least an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $| \lambda | = 1$ ). Show that
$$x \mapsto Ax$$
is not structurally stable.

A $C^r$ map $f$ is $C^m$ -structurally stable ($1 \leq m \leq r$) if there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $f$ in the $C^m$-topology such that every map $g \in U$ is topologically conjugate to $f$.
$f$ is structurally stable if $f$ is $C^1$-structurally stable.

Can someone give me a hint? Thank you!

Comment: To prove that such diffeomorphism isn't structurally stable you have to provide a pair of diffeomorphisms in each neighbourhood of $A$ that for sure aren't conjugated. What if you consider only linear diffeomorphisms in these neighbourhoods? Can you find this pair of diffeomorphisms?

Comment: I think that such a pair of diffeomorphisms could be the differential $DA_x$ for every $x$,but I don't know how to prove that it is not topologically conjugate to $A$. Can you give me more hints? Thank you!

Comment: You have to play around the fixed point. There is everything known about behaviour near the fixed point of linear diffeomorphism. Few additional hints: do you know, how eigenvalues of diffeomorphism behave when you perturb it slightly? If you plot eigenvalues on complex plane and there is at least one at unit circle (i.e., non-hyperbolic diffeomorphism), how can they move on complex plane when you perturb diffeomorphism? Also, when two linear diffeomorphisms are conjugated to each other?

Comment: I've been thinking about these hints, but I have not managed to solve the problem. Could you please help me to solve this ? Thank you!

Comment: But did you manage to answer all of my questions? If you did, then in my opinion it puts everything in right places.

Comment: I have not been able to answer the first question. I managed to answer the last question only: two linear diffeomorphisms $f$ and $g$ are topologically conjugated if there exists a homeomorphism $h$ such that $f h = h g$.

Comment: But that's just the general definition of conjugacy. There is a clear criterion when two linear hyperbolic diffeomorphisms are conjugated. It is mentioned in Katok and Hasselblatt's book, as far as I remember (not only there, of course). Speaking about eigenvalues: if you change matrix entries continuously, eigenvalues change continuously too. Maybe when you find criterion for conjugacy of two linear diffeomorphism you'll understand why the case when there are eigenvalues on the unit circle is important and non-trivial.